# Windows - Execute ruby functions in separate process

Tags: ruby, windows, process, fork, spawn

I'm trying to execute Ruby functions in separate processes on my Windows system. On Mac, I used the `Fork` method. But that doesn't work on Windows. I also tried the `spawn` method. But that doesn't seem to work either.

```
def test_1
  puts "Hello"
end

def test_2
  puts " World"
end
```

## On Mac (Works)

```
pid_1 = Fork.do
  test_1
end

pid_2 = Fork.do
  test_2
end

Process.waitall
```

## On Windows (Doesn't work)

```
pid_1 = Process.spawn(test_1)
pid_2 = Process.spawn(test_2)
Process.waitall

Exception: NoMethodError - undefined method `spawn' for Process:Module
```

Ruby version: 2.0
Can someone help me in understanding what I'm missing.

Edit: Found the issue. The Ruby version was old (1.8.7) which doesn't implement this method.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "doesn't work"? What happens exactly each way?

Comment: Updated with the exception.

Comment: `Process` is a module, not a class. I've never used it, but I would do first a `include Process` in your class definition, and then use it simply as `spawn(test_1)`.

Comment: What is `Fork.do`? Is it some custom wrapper for `Process.fork` or smth like this?